# Fragment - Back fragments not opening with correct sort

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragment; `FragmentA`,`FragmentB` and `FragmentC`. First I open `FragmentA` then `FragmentB` and at the end `FragmentC`.
 On `FragmentC`, when I press back button(my custom back button) `FragmentB` is opening properly. But on `FragmentB`, when I press back button, `FragmentC` is opening again instead of `FragmentA`. So an infinite loop occurs between `FragmentC` and `FragmentB`

I use this code to open a Fragment;

```
 public void change(Fragment fragment) {

    ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

            .replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment, "fragment")
            .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

I use this code to go back to a Fragment;

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```